# Should tag wikis answer the "what is this" question?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wikis

See the tag wiki for [depth-of-field](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depth-of-field): https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/depth-of-field/info. This has a relatively in-depth article explaining the term. On the other hand, the new SE blog post about [tags and tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) talks about tag wikis mostly in terms of *defining what the term means to the community*, and *how it should be used here*.

Should articles like the above be actively discouraged?

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between the tag *wiki* and the tag wiki *excerpt*.

The excerpt needs to be ~400 characters of awesomely succinct plain text; the full wiki has no such length or style limitations.

Still, I do think it's important in both cases to begin with "what does this tag mean to your community" first, as in:

> which questions should have this tag, and why?

Because, let's face it -- people can get a definition of the depth of field effect in a lot of places. What they *can't* get, however, is guidance and advice on usage of this tag in **your community**.

Comment: Should the tag wiki excerpt be considered the first paragraph of the tag wiki, or should it be duplicated?

Comment: @matt perhaps, I think you'll have to play with it and see what works. The excerpt needs to be quite good as it will be seen most.

Comment: With the way it's presented right now, considering the exerpt to be a punchy lede works pretty well, I think. The full wiki should _expand_ but not repeat. But if the presentation of the exerpt on the full wiki page changes that might change too.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing a tag I want a quick answer to the question 'Is this the appropriate tag?'. At that stage I really couldn't be bothered with reading a full article.